# Sharepoint enterprise search grey line

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, query-rule

When I search in the Sharepoint Enterpise Search. Sometimes the gray line is displayed. What are the default settings for displaying the gray line in SharePoint Enterprise Search?

[image]

Comment: Solution as question is clear for me: What you see is a "Result Block". Result blocks are set by "Query Rules". Query rules can be set on Search Service Application level (in Central Administration) or within your Enterprise Search Center. Create a query rule to get a feeling for that: Central Admin - Search Service application - Query Rules - select Local SharePoint Results - New Query Rule - "Query Matches Keyword Exactly" - set "pptx" - Add Result Block - Save it. Open Search Center and search for "pptx". You will see your all new result block somewhere in your results.